Integration ai model in chart.js in ReactJs
`I am integrating Ai model Citrus Disease Prediction .
I am facing issues that I am unable to get the values of model in the chartjs. Please guide me where I am doing wrong.
This is my Test component where I  receving the model output from Main componet and passing the data to the chart .`
import React from 'react';
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { Chart, ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend, Title } from 'chart.js';

Chart.register(ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend, Title);

const Test = ({ diseaseInfo }) => {
  const data = {
    labels: ['affected', 'fresh'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [Math.round(parseInt(diseaseInfo.confidence)), Math.round(parseInt(diseaseInfo.confidence - 100))],
      backgroundColor: ['rgb(210, 69, 69)', 'rgb(65, 176, 110)'],
      borderWidth: 2,
      radius: '40%'
    }]
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Results of Disease Prediction system</h2>
      <Doughnut data={data} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;


Here is the main component where i am receving  data from the model and passing props here to the Testing component.
import React, { useState } from "react";
import banner from "../assets/home-banner.png";
import rectangle from "../assets/Rectangle 11.png";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { BsCloudUploadFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import axios from 'axios';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';
import Pie from "./Donut";
import Test from "./Test";

const Main = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [diseaseInfo, setDiseaseInfo] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [showDoughnut, setshowDoughnut] = useState(false);

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    setImage(file);
  };

  const handleAnalyze = async () => {
    try {
      if (!image) {
        throw new Error('Please select a file.');
      }

      setLoading(true);

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', image);

      const response = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict", formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      });

      setDiseaseInfo(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
      setshowDoughnut(true);
      toast.success(`Data fetched successfully.`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error analyzing image:', error);
      setLoading(false);
      toast.error(error.message || 'An error occurred.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="printable-content">
      <Test diseaseInfo={diseaseInfo} />
      <motion.div className="md:flex md:text-center md:bg-cover overflow-hidden md:bg-no-repeat md:text-3xl md:text-white h-[9rem] md:h-[15rem] bg-cover bg-no-repeat text-2xl text-white py-8"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url('${banner}')`,
        }}>
        <motion.h1 initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0 }} whileInView={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }} transition={{ duration: 1 }}
          className="text-center md:text-[10vh] md:m-auto md:leading-[4rem] xl:leading-[rem]">
          Citrus Disease <label htmlFor="">Detection</label>
          <br />
          <label className="text-orange-500">Services</label>
        </motion.h1>
      </motion.div>

      <section className="flex flex-col md:flex-row md:justify-around md:items-center md:py-8 overflow-hidden p-7">
        <motion.div initial={{ opacity: 0, x: -100 }} whileInView={{ opacity: 1, x: 0 }} transition={{ duration: 1 }}>
          <img src={rectangle} className="w-82 p-6 md:w-80" alt="Rectangle" />
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div initial={{ opacity: 0, x: 100 }} whileInView={{ opacity: 1, x: 1 }} transition={{ duration: 1 }}
          className="w-full md:w-1/2 md:pl-8 flex-wrap ">
          <h1 className="font-bold text-2xl md:text-4xl text-center pb-5 md:pb-10">
            Citrus <label className="text-orange-500 md:text-orange-500"> Diseases</label>
          </h1>
          <p className="overflow-hidden text-md md:text-lg md:text-left leading-loose text-justify p-3">
            Leaves from healthy plants and plants infected with prevalent
            diseases (citrus greening, citrus canker, scab, greasy spot). Citrus
            greening is the most serious citrus disease caused by a bacteria
            which is spread by the Asian citrus psyllid (ACP). ACP is a tiny
            insect that transmits the bacteria to the tree when feeding.
          </p>
        </motion.div>
      </section>

      {showDoughnut ? (
        <Pie diseaseInfo={diseaseInfo} />
      ) : (
        <div className="upload-section  md:m-auto rounded md:shadow-orange-800 md:mb-5 shadow-2xl overflow-hidden m-5 shadow-200 h-96 pt-8 flex flex-col items-center justify-center md:w-[87vw]">
          <div className="border-2 border-slate-300 rounded-lg overflow-hidden md:w-60 w-56 h-60 shadow-2xl flex flex-col items-center justify-center bg-gray-200">
            <label htmlFor="fileInput" className="file-label">
              <BsCloudUploadFill className="size-16 m-auto hover:cursor-pointer hover:text-orange-500 transition-all duration-200 " />
              Drop your picture here
            </label>
            <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="input" className="hidden" accept="image/*" onChange={handleFileChange} />
            {image && (
              <p> {image.name}</p>
            )}
          </div>
          <button onClick={handleAnalyze} className="m-auto flex">
            <h1 className="md:w-32 md:p-2 p-1 gap-y-4 rounded-xl bg-orange-500 md:text-xl  text-white text-xl cursor-pointer">
              Analyze
            </h1>
          </button>
        </div>
      )}

      <div className="flex justify-center shadow-2xl ">
        <div>
          {loading && <div><span className="loading loading-ball loading-lg text-orange-500"></span></div>}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;


`
I am trying to passing the data to the ChartJs donughnut componet  which I am getting from the model .
Two things the model is generating

Disease Name
Confidence

Here is the model output
model output
